# Java Entity Class: How to add/edit items in an entity with joined columns?

Tags: java, entity, join

I've read several topics about this as well as the API and I feel like I am on the right track; however, I must still not be understanding enough to get it working, because.. well it doesn't work!

I have the following 2 tables: TODO and JOBTYPE

TODO table has TDTDKEY (PK) and TDJTKEY(FK?)
JOBTYPE table has JTJTKEY (PK) and JTCODE

[image]

As you can see Todo.tdjtkey corresponds to jobtype.jtjtkey and my goal is to retrieve the jtcode rather than the key.

The Entity classes look partially like this:

**Todo.java**

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TDTDKEY")
private String primaryKey;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TDJTKEY", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private JobType jobType;

public Todo() {
}

public Todo(String primaryKey) {
    this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
}

public String getPrimaryKey() {
    return primaryKey;
}

public void setPrimaryKey(String primaryKey) {
    this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
}

public JobType getJobType() {
    return jobType;
}

public void setJobType(JobType jobType) {
    this.jobType = jobType;
}
```

**JobType.java**

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "JTJTKEY")
private String primaryKey;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "jobType")
private Todo todo;
@Column(name = "JTCODE")
private String jobCode;

public JobType() {
}

public JobType(String primaryKey) {
    this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
}

public String getPrimaryKey() {
    return primaryKey;
}

public void setPrimaryKey(String primaryKey) {
    this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
}

public String getJobCode() {
    return jobCode;
}

public void setJobCode(String jobCode) {
    this.jobCode = jobCode;
}
```

So when I do a named query for `Todo.findAll` it gives me TDTDKEY (i.e. TD00000001) and the associated TDJTKEY CODE (i.e. PICS PGM).

Now, now that I finally got my select working, I am trying to see how I can add/edit.

So for example, if I am on TD00000001 and I want to change PROG to SUPPORT.

If I try it the normal way of `sv.setJobType(txtJobType.getText());` it doesn't work and gives me:

```
method setJobType in class entity.Todo cannot be applied to given types;
  required: entity.JobType
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to entity.JobType by method invocation conversion
```

So that's more or less understandable to me, but I am clueless on how I could perform an update to Todo table? Somehow I need it to find SUPPORT in JobType.java and then get the JTJTKEY of it and put it as a new TDJTKEY in the Todo.java?

Any help/hints are appreciated!

**Edit:** The following code works as per answer! Thanks!

```
String jpql = "select jobType from JobType jobType where jobType.jobCode = :code";
JobType otherJobType = WWEntityManager.entityManager.createQuery(jpql, JobType.class).setParameter("code", txtJobType.getText()).getSingleResult();

todoEntity.getJobType().removeTodo(todoEntity);
todoEntity.setJobType(otherJobType);
otherJobType.addTodo(todoEntity);
```

And my entity classes look like this now

Todo.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TDJTKEY", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private JobType jobType;
```

JobType.java

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Todo.class, mappedBy="jobType")
private Collection jobTypes;
```

Of course I had to add the appropriate methods for remove and add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have 2 TODO rows with the same job key. So, either the data are wrong, or they're right but your association should then be ManyToOne/OneToMany instead of OneToOne/OneToOne.

Now, regarding your question. If you want to change the code of the job of a todo, the answer is very simple:

```
todo.getJobType().setJobCode("newCode");
```

If, in fact, you want the TODO to refer to another, existing JobType (supposing the association is a ManyToOne):

```
todo.getJobType().removeTodo(todo); // remove the todo from its current job type
todo.setJobType(otherJobType); // set the new job type in todo
otherJobType.addTodo(todo); // add the todo to its new job type
```

Now the question is: how to get the reference to this `otherJobType`. If you have its ID, the answer is simple:

```
JobType otherJobType = em.find(JobType.class, otherJobTypeId);
```

If you only have its code, you'll need to execute a query to find it. Assuming the code is unique:

```
String jpql = "select jobType from JobType jobType where jobType.jobCode = :code";
JobType otherJobType = em.createQuery(jpql, JobType.class)
                         .setParameter("code", otherJobTypeCode)
                         .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: You are right in every way! I changed the relation to ManyToOne/OneToMany, and used collection together with remove/add methods. Everything is working now (until I break it again)! Thank You!